# maven compilation error package dose not exist

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using maven for build web project in eclipse IDE but when i try to execute build command have this error:

```
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\monitoring\manager\UserSessionInfoManager.java:[9,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseAccountingManager.java:[7,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseAccountingManager.java:[8,28] error: package com.datx.core.manager does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseAccountingManager.java:[9,26] error: package com.datx.core.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseAccountingManager.java:[13,59] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseAccountingManager.java:[13,45] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\model\BaseAccountingAuditableEntity.java:[20,60] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\monitoring\dao\UserSessionInfoDAO.java:[11,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\monitoring\dao\UserSessionInfoDAO.java:[18,40] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\monitoring\manager\UserSessionInfoManager.java:[24,11] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\monitoring\web\filter\UserSessionInfoFilter.java:[8,31] error: package com.datx.web.filter.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\monitoring\web\filter\UserSessionInfoFilter.java:[10,43] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseAccountingManager.java:[27,11] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\common\model\AccUser.java:[12,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\common\model\AccUser.java:[13,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\common\model\AccUser.java:[18,29] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\common\model\AccUser.java:[20,17] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseBussinessAccountingManager.java:[6,28] error: package com.datx.core.manager does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseBussinessAccountingManager.java:[10,52] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccDocumentManager.java:[36,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccDocumentManager.java:[37,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseTreeManager.java:[8,26] error: package com.datx.core.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\BaseTreeManager.java:[13,48] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccDocumentManager.java:[70,11] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseAccountingHibernateDAO.java:[13,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseAccountingHibernateDAO.java:[14,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseAccountingHibernateDAO.java:[15,26] error: package com.datx.core.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseAccountingHibernateDAO.java:[18,65] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseAccountingHibernateDAO.java:[18,51] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\model\CurrentStatus.java:[16,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\SecondaryCodeManager.java:[23,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseTreeHibernateDAO.java:[11,26] error: package com.datx.core.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseTreeHibernateDAO.java:[13,53] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccountTreeManager.java:[21,30] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\TreePropertyHibernateDAO.java:[10,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\BaseAccountingHibernateDAO.java:[32,15] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\AccUserHibernateDAO.java:[8,34] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\dao\AccUserHibernateDAO.java:[10,41] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\DetailedTreeTypeManager.java:[11,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\DetailedTreeTypeManager.java:[35,11] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\FinancialStatementsManager.java:[18,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\FinancialStatementsManager.java:[19,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\FinancialStatementsManager.java:[94,11] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[23,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[24,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.resource does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[25,41] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.filter does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[26,41] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.filter does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[27,41] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.filter does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[28,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[29,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[30,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[31,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[32,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[33,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[34,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[35,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[36,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.form does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[37,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.web.view does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[40,31] error: package com.datx.web.filter.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[41,31] error: package com.datx.web.filter.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[42,31] error: package com.datx.web.filter.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[43,29] error: package com.datx.web.form.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[44,29] error: package com.datx.web.form.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[52,11] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[11,32] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[13,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[14,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[15,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[16,39] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.resource does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[18,31] error: package com.datx.web.filter.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[20,52] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[115,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\resources\proxy\accounting\AdminProxyResources.java:[119,44] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[13,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[15,32] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[22,32] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[23,30] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[24,38] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.manager does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[25,36] error: package com.datx.usermanagement.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[27,31] error: package com.datx.web.filter.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[29,36] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\form\CreateBackOfficeUserForm.java:[3,29] error: package com.datx.web.view.core does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\form\CreateBackOfficeUserForm.java:[5,46] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[70,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\web\accounting\resources\AccUserManagementAdminResource.java:[105,47] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\log\Manager\AuditLogManager.java:[8,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\log\Manager\AuditLogManager.java:[9,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\log\Manager\AuditLogManager.java:[10,28] error: package com.datx.core.manager does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\log\Manager\AuditLogManager.java:[14,37] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\log\AuditLog.java:[11,26] error: package com.datx.core.model does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\log\AuditLog.java:[16,30] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[32,9] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\monitoring\manager\UserSessionFailureAttemptsManager.java:[6,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[35,9] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[53,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[67,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[81,48] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[176,8] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\accounting\manager\AccUserManager.java:[180,28] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] \integrated-accounting\com.datx.integratedAccounting.core\src\main\java\com\datx\log\dao\AuditLogHibernateDAO.java:[15,24] error: package com.datx.core.dao does not exist
    [INFO] 100 errors
```

Comment: You are missing dependencies?

Comment: no but i am insert jar files for packages in my project